# ListView stack from bottom - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview and I'm using a header, I'm also using stack from bottom, I need the header to be always at the top of the screen no matter how many items are there.

The problem is that the header is being treated as a regular item so when the listview has no item(s) other than the header it will put/draw it at the bottom, is is possible to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't understand your question ._.
What do you mean by stack? what stack?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, however the "header" should then be a separate view that's placed before the `ListView`, e.g.:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This way it will always be positioned before all the items.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will make two views, so when I scroll the listview the view above won't be affected.

Comment: @amnaiuamuli sounds like exactly what you want `I need the header to be always at the top of the screen no matter how many items are there`. If it's not then please explain it properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
ListView somelist;
```

OnCreate...blahblah

```
somelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.somelist);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
R.layout.headerforyourlistview, somelist, false);

somelist.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

This should make it scroll with your listview but stay on top. This is not the answer to your original question but it the answer to what you seem to want.

Comment: And how does this answer deserve a downvote? I have it working perfectly exactly as he stated in more than one of my apps.